# How to fix that my timer gives no Errors whatsoever

Tags: javascript, html, timer

Im making a timer just for fun, and i encountered a problem. When i press the start Button (html) it just does nothing. It gives no errors and no help in F12 Mode.

I tried removing p.innerHTML and added it to all other variables.

```
function start() {
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    var displayNum = Number(display.innerHTML);
    setInterval(function () {
      displayNum + 0.001;
      var stringNumber = displayNum.toString();
      stringNumber = display.innerHTML;
    }, 1);
  }
```

I want it to add 0.001 every millisecond. Like a timer...

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the number back into the DOM.

In **setInterval()** try doing `display.innerHTML = displayNum`.

Comment: I do have another problem now. The display.innerHTML is just 0.001 now. If i press the button again it bugs and glitches to 0.001 and 0.002 constantly.


`function start() {
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  var displayNum = Number(display.innerHTML);
  setInterval(function () {
    var final = displayNum + 0.001;
    display.innerHTML = final;
  }, 1);
}`

Comment: You also need to keep the current count in memory, like so:

displayNum = displayNum + 0.001;